# Artifactory: What permission set is needed to allow repo creation, without assigning admin rights?

Tags: artifactory

I'm looking to grant a user the ability to create repos, but I am unable to find a permission set that will allow this without assigning admin rights to the user. The Artifactory permissions knowledge base article was sadly no help.

Answer (score 1):

`Create a repository` action requires an admin user, as described in [the REST APIs docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateRepository).